# JavaScript form validation function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I want to validate this form and I have the javascript written but when I press <kbd>submit</kbd> it doesnt do anything.

Only the `pattern=[a-zA-Z]` work

```js
function validation() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var surname = document.getElementById('surname').value;
  var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;

  if (name == '' || surname == '' || message == '' || email == '') {
    document.getElementById("eresult").innerHTML = "All fields required"
    return false;
  } else if (name.length < 2) {
    document.getElementById("eresult").innerHTML = "Name must be atleast 2 charachters"
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<aside id="sidebar">
  <div class="dark">
    <form action="#" name="form" method="POST" onsubmit="return validation();">
      <h3>Get A Quote</h3>

      <div>
        <label>Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]*">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Surname</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Surname" pattern="[a-zA-Z]*">
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>Email</label><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>Message</label><br>
        <textarea type="message" name="message" id="email" minlength="1" maxlength="200" placeholder="Message(max 200 characters)"></textarea>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <div id="eresult" style="color:red;"></div>
  </div>
</aside>
<footer>
  <p>Renars Web Design, Copyright &copy; 2019</p>
</footer>
```

I expect if I dont enter all fields it should say "All Fields required"
but it just submits the form.

Comment: did you try printing the values to see what they contain?

Comment: Why don't you use `required` tag instead of a javascript function?

Comment: Try to get the form fields like   `var name = document.forms["form"]['name'].value;` . https://codepen.io/binishjohn/pen/zyXxpz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Using the "required" attribute:

Just add the `required` attribute to each input if you want to make an input mandatory.

When this attribute is set, the form won't submit (and will display an error message) when the input is empty (the input will also be considered invalid).

---

Check the following **Code Snippet** and try to submit the form without filling some or all of the fields to see how the `required` attribute works:

```html
<form action="#" name="form" method="POST">
  <div>
    <label>Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]*" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Surname</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Surname" pattern="[a-zA-Z]*" required>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Email</label><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Message</label><br>
    <textarea type="message" name="message" id="email" minlength="1" maxlength="200" placeholder="Message(max 200 characters)" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

### Using a JavaScript function:

There are a couple of things that you need to fix in your JS as well as HTML:

1. Change your **`input type="submit"`** to **`button type="button"`** so that the submit button will run the function first instead of directly trying to submit the form. Also, make sure to change the **`name`** attribute value and **`id`** attribute value **`submit`** to something else, like **`submitBtn`** or **`submitForm`** so that you can manually run the **`submit()`** method later in the function.
2. Add an element with an id **`"eresult"`** where your validation function can push the error messages to.
3. Add a click listener to your submit button to run your validation function.
4. Change the **`id`** attribute value of your **`textarea`** element to **`message`**.
5. Use the same **`if/else statement`** that you already have but add a **`return false;`** to your **`else if`** statement too and add a **`form.submit()`** to your final **`else`** statement above the **`return true;`**.

**N.B.** *We had to change the `name` and `id` attribute of your submit button earlier so that `form.submit()` will reference the `submit()` method and not the submit button in the validation function.*

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of what I had described above:

```js
/* JavaScript */

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var surname = document.getElementById('surname').value;
  var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  if(name=='' || surname=='' || message=='' || email==''){
    document.getElementById("eresult").innerHTML = "All fields required"
    return false;
  }
  else if(name.length<2){
    document.getElementById("eresult").innerHTML = "Name must be atleast 2 charachters"
    return false;
  }

  else{
    form.submit();
    return true;
    
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<form action="#" name="form" method="POST">
  <div>
    <label>Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]*">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Surname</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Surname" pattern="[a-zA-Z]*">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Email</label><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Message</label><br>
    <textarea type="message" name="message" id="message" minlength="1" maxlength="200" placeholder="Message(max 200 characters)"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="button" name="submitBtn">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="eresult"></div>
```

Comment: But if I wanted to do this with Javascript ( I know it is way longer and unnecasary) then what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code. View the console error log.

You have an incorrect id in the message textarea.

In other words, "email" identifier is duplicated.