# Ways to correctly disable Submit button during form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms, firefox

I'm using the following approach to disable my `Submit` button in the form right after the form begins submission. (The reason I need this is because the server-side script calls [`checkdnsrr($email, 'MX');`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php) that may hold it off for several seconds if provided email address is incorrect.)

Here's approx HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="contact.php">
<input type="email" name="email" id="idEmail" maxlength="256" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" />
<input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="return onSubmitDisable(this);" />
</form>
```

and then in JavaScript:

```
function onSubmitDisable(obj)
{
    obj.form.submit();
    obj.value = "Sending...";
    obj.disabled = 'disabled';
    return true;
}
```

This kinda works, except that I just encountered an issue in Firefox. Let me give you steps:

If you fill out the form by adding last space in the email address field:

[image]

and then hit `Enter` on the keyboard, the Firefox will invoke my `onSubmitDisable` function:

[image]

but something will fail in the submission process, I'm assuming due to Firefox's form validation that will attempt to show an error in the email form UI:

[image]

But `form.submit()` will either not do anything, or fail. It doesn't seem to raise an exception though.

So as a result my form will hang indefinitely with the disabled `Submit` button in that case.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your `input type="submit"` to `input type="button"` so that the submit button will run the function first instead of directly trying to submit the form. Also, make sure to change the `name` attribute value and `id` attribute value `submit` to something else, like `submitBtn` or `submitForm` so that you can manually run the `submit()` method later on from inside your `onSubmitDisable()` function`++`.
2. You need to add a name attribute to your form with a value say, `"myForm"` so you can reference it later when you want to submit it.
3. Also, your current function is not correctly referencing the `value` attribute when you want to change the "send" text to "Sending". You need to replace `obj.value` with `obj.target.value`. Also, `obj.disabled` is a boolean, so you need to assign it to `true` when the send button is clicked.
4. Finally, you need to move the `submit()` method to the end so that it will run last after changing "send" to "sending" and disabling the button. Do make sure you reference the name of the form, here "myForm" in your submit method like this `myForm.submit();`.

`++`*We had to change the name and id attribute of your submit button so that `form.submit()` will reference the `submit()` **method** and not the submit button **element** in the validation function. This was why your `submit()` wasn't working as it should in your original code earlier.*

---

Run the following Code Snippet or check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/udc40eLm/14/) for a practical example of the submit button changing text from "send" to "sending" and disabling it while sending the form as described above:

```js
function onSubmitDisable(obj) {
    obj.target.value = "Sending...";
    obj.disabled = true;
    myForm.submit();
    return true;
}

document.querySelector("input[name='submitBtn']").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  onSubmitDisable(e);
});
```

```html
<form method="POST" name="myForm" action="contact.php">
<input type="email" name="email" id="idEmail" maxlength="256" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" />
<input type="button" name="submitBtn" value="Send" />
</form>
```

---

**Source: [JavaScript form validation function is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54216006/javascript-form-validation-function-is-not-working/54216058#54216058)**

Comment: this doesn't look like it's working either as a snippet or in the fiddle

Comment: @DCR, Can you clarify what doesnt work exactly because I checked the snippet as well as the jsfiddle as well as recreate this on my local wamp server and it's working as it should. Also, I didn't downvote your answer earlier even though it doesn't address what the OP wanted, in case you're wondering :)

Comment: @AndrewL64: the downside of changing the `html` submit input tag into a button is that if the user disables scripts, or if their web browser fails running the script (in case of an older version) the form will not be submittable. Which is a **really bad** design. I'm not into downvoting, but sorry, this suggestion deserves it.

Comment: @c0000fd Even a dying browser like IE supports a JavaScript click event on a button in a form so I'm not really sure what you're trying to say and if by disabling scripts, you mean disabling JavaScript, that would mean 99% of the websites (or "most of the websites" if you're the literal type) on the internet would barely work lol I'm not even using es7+ or some "fancy new stuff" by JavaScript in the code above. Just standard JavaScript and suggestions on standard JavaScript coding practices but yeah, I guess it deserves it lol Anyway, cheers my guy. Glad you fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

your solution doesn't seem to work!

```js
var objForm = document.getElementById('idForm');
console.log(objForm);
objForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e)
{
    var objBtn = document.getElementById('idBtnSend');
    objBtn.value = "Sending...";
    objBtn.disabled = 'disabled';
   
})
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="idForm" action="contact.php">
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="idBtnSend" />
</form>
```

Comment: run the snippet when you click on send the page is being submitted and the input box disappears.  check the jquery example I provided earlier.  BTW, jquery minified is just 19 kb

Comment: I'm not debugging this buggy website https://i.imgur.com/0gnSyzb.png Obviously `contact.php` is not a part of SO.

Comment: doesn't work on jsfiddle either so I suspect it's not the site but your code.  https://jsfiddle.net/0m41aquy/

Comment: 16 years old.  How old are you? and your fiddle doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just disable the button via onsubmit?

Seems more intuitive IMHO.

[edit] Added debugger so you can see that the button is disabled.

```js
function disableSendButton(formElement)
{
  let submitBtn = formElement.lastElementChild;
  submitBtn.value = "Sending...";
  submitBtn.disabled = true;
debugger
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" onsubmit="disableSendButton(this)" action="contact.php">
  <input type="email" name="email" id="idEmail" maxlength="256" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Comment: that's what my original code does. And as I explained in my original post, that doesn't seem to always work in Firefox. So adding it thru `addEventListener` seems to resolve the issue there.

Comment: Well, you had it as an `onclick` on the submit button but, from what I can tell in Firefox, with my solution above, Firefox will complain on the _before_ trying to send it. Firefox didn't do that when I tried your code.

Answer (score -1):

OK. I think I got it. Plain and simple without dragging in any libraries. Just raw JavaScript.

So for HTML:

```
<form method="POST" id="idForm" action="contact.php">
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="idBtnSend" />
</form>
```

Here's the JavaScript to disable `Submit` button. Works in the latest Chrome, FF, Edge and Safari (in iOS):

```
var objForm = document.getElementById('idForm');
objForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e)
{
    var objBtn = document.getElementById('idBtnSend');
    objBtn.value = "Sending...";
    objBtn.disabled = 'disabled';
}
);  // ok, I forgot to copy this last line in my original posting
```

Answer (score -2):

Really simple if you use jquery.  get rid of the onclick event, add an id to form and use the following:

```js
$("#myform").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="contact.php" id='myform'>
<input type="email" name="email" id="idEmail" maxlength="256" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" />
<input type="submit" value="Send"  />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I do not see any reasons for bringing in the mass of code in JQuery just for this little function. Do you know what it uses internally for that callback?

Comment: sorry, no. but do you really think it makes a performance difference that users will notice

Comment: @DCR Yes, using jQuery does have a performance difference compared to using only vanilla JS.

Comment: @DCR that's one of the reasons why half of the websites these days make my (somewhat older) Chromebook crawl to a halt.